Numb @njit @jitclass memory accumulation in loops
We are encountering a memory accumulation issue when using a Numba class to append arrays of floats to a list within a loop. Despite clearing the list before each iteration, the memory usage continues to grow proportionally with the loop size. Interestingly, this problem only arises when the class is implemented using Numba; it doesn't occur with a standard Python class.
Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Here is a minimum working (or "bugging") example. the out put is a positive number (i.e. more memory used after running the script). This is not the case if a normal pyhton class is used (remove the @jitclass() )
Tested for Specs:
OS:    Linux SMP x86_64    |  22.04.1-Ubuntu
Numba: 0.59.1              |  0.58.1
Numpy: 1.26.4              |  1.24.1
Python:3.11.8  GCC 12.3.0  | 3.11.0 GCC 11.3.0
import numba.experimental.jitclass as jitclass
import numba
import random
import numpy as np
import psutil
import os

@jitclass()
class testing:
points : numba.types.List(numba.types.Array(numba.types.float64, 1, "C"))

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize point structure
        self.points = [np.zeros(1)]
        self.points.clear()
    
    def compute(self):
    
        # Clear possible previous points
        self.points.clear()
        
        l=random.randint(0,1000)
        #l=10
        for k in range(l):
            self.points.append(np.array([np.float64(k)]))
        
        return 0

a=testing()

process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
base_memory_usage = process.memory_info().rss
for i in range(1000):
a.compute()

memory_usage = process.memory_info().rss
loop_memory_usage = memory_usage - base_memory_usage

print('RAM Used (GB):',loop_memory_usage/1e9)

Thank you in advance!
PS: Note that we found a way to solve this by making a List of List instead of a List of Arrays but we do not understand why the issue occurs in the first place.

I do not think we can help much here. This clearly seems a bug of Numba so I strongly advise you to fill an issue on their Github bug tracker so Numba developers can fix it.

My guess is that the array objects are not collected certainly because or a missing free / reference counting check in the generated code (so a bug/leak).

Is your actual code appending arrays of size 1, or have you simplified this from your actual code? If so, be aware that List(float64) will be much more efficient than List(array(float64)).

@NickODell just to be clear, you should use regular Pythonfloat objects

@juanpa.arrivillaga In Numba, lists are typed and floating-point numbers are native so they are either nb.float64 or nb.float32 (which are basically alias types of Numpy). float is nb.float64 in Numba and it is not a CPython object. However, in a pure Python code, then yes float objects should be used instead yes (faster and more convenient).

Thank you all for your comments!
We have managed to solve the issue:
The problem was a mixing of reflected and typed lists that cause the issue.
If we correctly define and initialize "points", the list is correctly cleared after each loop and no RAM accumulates.
by changing
points : numba.types.List(numba.types.Array(numba.types.float64, 1, "C"))

to
points : numba.types.ListType(numba.types.Array(numba.types.float64, 1, "C"))

and
self.points = [np.zeros(1)]

to
self.points = numba.typed.List((np.zeros(0),))

the issue can be solved.
Here is a working example:
import numba.experimental.jitclass as jitclass
import numba
import random
import numpy as np
import psutil
import os

@jitclass
class testing:
    points : numba.types.ListType(numba.types.Array(numba.types.float64, 1, "C"))
    
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize point structure
        self.points = numba.typed.List((np.zeros(0),))
        self.points.clear()
    
    def compute(self):
    
        # Clear possible previous points
        self.points.clear()
        
        l=random.randint(0,1000)
        #l=10
        for k in range(l):
            self.points.append(np.array([np.float64(k)]))
        
        return 0

a=testing()

# checking ram usage here for python  (i dont know how to check ram usage of numba)
for j in range(20):
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    base_memory_usage = process.memory_info().rss    
    for i in range(1000):
        a.compute()
    
    memory_usage = process.memory_info().rss
    loop_memory_usage = memory_usage - base_memory_usage
    
    print('RAM Used:',loop_memory_usage/1e9)

